# jQuery UI Datepicker Your selected date is a Saturday or Sunday

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Find Sol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FokGv.png)

I am using datepicker and if someone selects a Saturday or Sunday display alert mesage Your selected date is a Saturday or Sunday, do you wish to continue?

If user click on OK then it process otherwise it close window

```
<input type="text" name="inspectiondate <? echo $sno; ?>" id="inspectiondate<? echo $sno; ?>" placeholder="Date" class="required-entry date" style="width:100px !important;" readonly="readonly" autofocus require>

 <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN). 'adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif'; ?>" alt="" class="v-middle date" id="Idate<? echo $sno; ?>" title="Select Date"  onclick="setcal(<? echo $sno; ?>)">
```

Comment: please update it in your question

Comment: Vishal Ji I want if user click jquery date time picker select date if it click on sat or sun it process otherwise remove alert box and not allow to click on sat or sunday

Comment: so, when user select any date which is on the saturday or sunday you want to display aler, rigth ?

Comment: Vishal Modi - right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle event of your datepicker where you will get selected date's day of the week.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker functionality</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker-13" ).datepicker();

$("#datepicker-13")
.datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        console.log("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
        $(this).change();
    }
})
.on("change", function() {

   var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var dayOfWeek = date.getUTCDay();
if(dayOfWeek == 5 || dayOfWeek == 6)
{
//your alert code
    alert(dayOfWeek)
  }
});
         });
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <p>Enter Date: <input type = "text" id = "datepicker-13"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

you can check working demo in below link.

https://jsfiddle.net/bc4nr5we/

Comment: For that, you need to try somet own your self. If you find any issue then you can post for help. For that you can use bootsrap modals.

Comment: Great. Keep it up